# Trying to read from text file

Tags: java, list, file, text-files, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read the following from a text file:

```
12
650 64 1
16 1024 2
```

My attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String filnavn = "regneklynge.txt";
        Scanner innFil = null;
        try {
            File fil = new File(filnavn);
            innFil = new Scanner(fil);
            while (innFil.hasNextLine()) {
                String linje = innFil.nextLine(); 
                int tall = Integer.parseInt(linje);
                System.out.println(tall);
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Filen kunne ikke finnes");
        }
    }
}
```

The first number(12) Works fine, but then I get this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "650 64 1"
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" .. can you be a bit more specific about that part?

Comment: The first version you posted, with `s.hasNext() ` instead of `innFil.nextLine()`, solved the problem you are asking about now.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions:

- You need two while loops, one nested inside of the other
- the first one, the outer loop, you loop `while (innFile.hasNextLine()) {...}`
- inside this loop you call `String linje = innFile.nextLine();` once
- Then create a 2nd Scanner object, `Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(linje);`
- and create a 2nd *inner* while loop that loops `while (lineScanner.hasNextInt() {...}`
- inside of this loop, extract a single int via `int tall = lineScanner.nextInt();`
- and put it into your ArrayList.
- Be sure to call `lineScanner.close();` after exiting the inner while loop and before exiting the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are reading the full line:

```
String linje = innFil.nextLine();
```

You can't treat them as an Integer because it's already a String

```
int tall = Integer.parseInt(linje);
// linje now has this = "650 64 1"
```

So that provokes the Exception:
    java.lang.NumberFormatException

Here is an approach to print the numbers:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String filnavn = "regneklynge.txt";
        Scanner innFil = null;
        try {
            File fil = new File(filnavn);
            innFil = new Scanner(fil);
            while (innFil.hasNextLine()) {
                if (innFil.hasNextInt()) {
                    System.out.println(innFil.nextInt());
                } else {
                    innFil.next();
                }
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Filen kunne ikke finnes");
        }
    }
}
```